# Deformation after posing with armature

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

[image: Normal mesh and armature]

[image: Mesh after posing]
Whenever I try to pose this specific bone (the "Hips" bone) the two objects that are weight painted to it deform. I have parented the "Thigh" bones to the "Hip" bone and there is no deformation with those. Does anyone know what is happening, and how to fix it?

Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bKZgEpgq5TAVe7c8Y6dUe00hVLm5Xfax

Thanks, Felix

Comment: Please clarify your question or upload the .blend file: by now it's not clear what you want and what is not giving you the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hips are deforming because their vertices are weighted relatively to two bones: Hips and Spine. When you move the Hips bone the vertices receive two instructions: one (Hips) is telling to move, one (Spine) is telling to stay still: the result is the combination of theese two istances. If you remove from vertices the Spine asignement everything will be as desired. While you're editing your rig I suggest you to have Hips and Spine bones going from down to top (it's a good practice, when you will start animating you'll understand why).

[image]